# Which one is the right usage? I have/had completed my Midyear appraisal on May 20, 2018

Tags: word-usage

Which one is the right usage?

> I have completed my Midyear appraisal on May 20, 2018

or

> I had completed my Midyear appraisal on May 20, 2018

Comment: Neither is really right, without more context.  Completing the appraisal was a single event that happened in the past, so the [simple past](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-past-tense/) is most appropriate.

Comment: We don't use the present perfect when the time-phrase in the clause specifies a time in the past, like a date, or with words like *yesterday*, or phrases like *when I was a child* or *back then*.  The time phrase cannot exclude the present when the present perfect is used.

Comment: Please remember to accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark next to it! Have a good one!

Answer (score 2):

> I **had** completed my mid-year appraisal on May 20th, 2018.

or simply,

> I  completed my mid-year appraisal on May 20th, 2018.

would be correct!

"Had" is past tense, so if the current date is after May 20th, 2018, use "had."

Use "have" if you completed it in the past, but you aren't mentioning the date of completion.

> Ex) "I have completed my mid-year appraisal."

Comment: They're both grammatically correct, but "I had completed it on May 20th" sounds weird with no context, because it's using the past perfect for no apparent reason.  I would only use that if I was telling a story set in, say, June, but I needed to emphasize that at that time in the past, the appraisal had already been done.